# Как вывести задачу в отдельный поток не ожидая результата на C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, callback

Пишу callback бота для ВК. Если не отправить ответ за время, установленное ВК, то ВК отправляет на сервер ещё один запрос, а у меня выполняется тяжелая по времени работа и в условные 5 секунд никак уложиться нельзя. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы контроллер кидал обработку запроса в отдельный поток и не ожидая результата отправлял в ответ Http Ok. Как это можно организовать ?

Comment: С помощью [асинхронного программирования](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

Comment: `Task.Run(()=>{ ваш код })` ?

Comment: Я пробовал, но, почему-то, контроллер ждёт выполнения задачи

Comment: Так вы покажите что вы пробовали то?

Comment: @tym32167, такая `Task`'а может прервать свое выполнение, если веб-сервер решит освободить Thread и остановить приложение за отсутствием запросов к API. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60283722/is-it-allowed-to-use-task-run-in-an-asp-net-core-controller

Comment: @Exodium остановить сервер через 5 секунд после запроса?

Comment: @tym32167 Вы не знаете, насколько трудоемка по времени операция, которую планирует запустить топикстартер. 5 секунд не относятся к времени выполнения задачи.

Comment: @Exodium ну а вы не знаете, как он хостит приложение, ведь во многих веб серверах можно исключить засыпание потоков. Не понимаю, к чему у нас этот разговор вообще. Надеюсь, топикстартер сам добавит подробностей в вопрос. э

Comment: @tym32167 Сейчас бы отключать опции веб-сервера, которые позволяют оптимизировать нагрузку ОС и железа. Не несите чепуху. В любом случае `Task.Run` это bad practice в данном контексте.

Comment: @Exodium я не знаю о каком именно контексте вы говорите, я тут не вижу контекста. Ну и почему вы считаете тюнинг настроек веб сервера под проект чепухой тоже мне не понять. Очевидно, ваша реальность не совпадает с моей. И также очевидно, что это тупиковый разговор. Вот вы что ожидаете от меня услышать? Если хотите меня убедить в чем то, то приведите факты, а не мнение. Если вы не хотите меня ни в чем убеждать, то мы просто тратим время и пора сворачиваться.

Comment: [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: а вот это ^ уже похоже на агрумент. Спасибо, @AlexanderPetrov, почитаю на досуге.

Comment: @tym32167 Действительно был тупиковый разговор, нужно было сразу его прерывать, когда Вы стали отстаивать свое некорректное мнение, которое пошло вразрез ответу от MVP по ссылке из моего первого коммента.

Comment: @Exodium ну вот видите разницу - вы уже выносите свои вердикты по моему мнению, но я вам про ваше такого не говорил. Я уже упоминал, что наши реальности отличаются. В моей уже несколько веб проектов без засыпаний пула приложений, последний работает уже 2 года нон стоп на asp.net core 2 + IIS (с простоями только во время деплоймента), где я успешно эксплуатирую и бекграунд потоки, и таски, и кеш в памяти и все это без рестарта. Я считаю, что это мне дает право сказать, что `Task.Run` в `asp.net` применить можно в определенных случаях. Поделитесь своим опытом, если есть желание.

Comment: @Exodium вот мой [pet проект](https://github.com/tym32167/battleyemanager), работают 2 инстанса уже как 3 года без засыпаний, один на IIS, второй на linux+ngnix+kestrel (про линукс сервер его вообще запустили и забыли, работает без проблем, потому про сервер могу и соврать - не помню). Можете поглядеть код, сам код там не супер-супер конечно, но свою работу делает и не доставляет проблем. Там тоже можно встретить и таски, и потоки и чего только нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Вы хотите отдать ответ 200 клиенту не дожидаясь обработки запроса, то необходимо запустить отработку запроса при помощи `Task.Run` в параллельном потоке, а в основном выдать необходимый ответ. В контроллере это может выглядеть так:

```
    public ActionResult Action(RequestData data)
    {
        Task.Run(() => { service.DoWork(data); });

        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: дополню, важно чтобы service был singleton, либо внутри создавал свой скоуп и из него получал нужные сервисы, иначе может случиться так, что скоуп созданный для HTTP запроса будет высвобожден, а сама задача упадет в ObjectDisposedException

Comment: -1, такая Таска упадет в условиях продолжительного выполнения и выгрузки приложения веб-сервером. Правильный ответ дал в комментариях к вопросу @Alexander Petrov.

Comment: @Exodium необходимое поведение можно настроить на целевом сервере. Если речь про IIS что-то вроде startMode="AlwaysRunning" или увеличить idle timeout